# mate-panel clock applet non monospace font causes wiggling in notification area

Tags: fonts, mate, gtk3, css

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 mate desktop. I am customizing the mate-panel. I wanted to use the following digital [font](https://www.dafont.com/ds-digital.font?text=digital) and I added the following style to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```
#clock-applet-button.flat.toggle > box.horizontal > label {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
    font-family: DS-Digital;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    /*padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px; */
    /*letter-spacing: 3px;*/
    /*margin: 8px; 
    margin-left: 14px;
    margin-right: 14px;*/
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
    outline-offset: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    /*border-left-width: 50px;
    border-right-width: 50px;*/
    /*outline-width: 20px;*/     
}
```

It's wiggling when numbers condensed, for example its width changes when clock digits counts from `00` to `01`

I recorded it [image]

I tried adding margins, padding but they didn't work.
Is there a trick to fix it using `gtk css`?

Comment: Try setting a minimum width with `min-width: value` this way the background should always stay at or above given width. Here are the docs https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html see table 7

Comment: @MarkKirby Thank your for your solution. It works. You can post it as an answer. Digital   clock is still wiggling inside the background. At least your solution fixes the wiggling of entire systray.

Comment: Glad it got a bit better, the resizing on the numbers seems like it would be font related. Try editing the 1 in the font and making it twice as wide like the other numbers. You can see in the link you provided for the font that it need extra width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you are looking for is

```
min-width: value
```

This will stop the box from going below a set value in width.

[Here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html) you can see the documentation, box properties can be found in table 7.

To address your issue with the numbers still resizing, this is related to the font you chose. In [the link](https://www.dafont.com/ds-digital.font?text=digital) you give you can see the number 1 is only half the width of the other numbers.

To edit the .ttf file of a font you can use some thing like fontforge from the repos, it should be a simple task.

```
sudo apt install fontforge
```

Comment: I just managed to fix width of `1`. I got `font contain errors wrong direction` message. I had to fix them manually. Especially locating `perthousand` glyph took a long time. Because there is no search functionality for glyph names.